# Select, Join, AS "Selected" if they are in a table

Tags: select, join

I have 2 tables. One is Product_Colors.. the other is a bridge table Product_Colors_Bridge.. the bridge table only contains ProductID and ColorID..

I need a Stored Procedure that brings back ALL of the colors and ADDS a "Selected" field to the statement.

**Tables**
Product_Colors
ID, Color

Product_Colors_Bridge
ID, ProductID, ColorID

ColorID references Product_Colors.ID

**Ideal Result**
ID, Color, ProductID, ColorID, Selected (This field must be added using SQL)

**Where Selected field value is either TRUE or FALSE...**

Comment: What is the condition to decide if it's either true or false? And what DB are you using?

Comment: The condition is this.. I need all colors back (Not just the selected one) and I need to know based on ProductID whether or not the color is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without knowing your DB, a standard SQL query (not a stored procedure) could look like this:

```
SELECT
Color,
ProductID,
ColorID,
CASE WHEN ProductID IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END AS SELECTED
FROM
PRODUCT_COLORS C LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_COLORS_BRIDGE PC ON PC.COLORID=C.ID
```

With left outer join all the left table records (colors) are retained, and then you check directly in the select clause if a corrispondent color/product exists in the DB to return a 'selected' value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh wow! We are definitely getting some where. This is some what working. This works fine except one thing. It brings back ALL the colors for ALL the products. I just need to bring back the information for one product. How do we ad a WHERE CLAUSE????

Comment: GOT IT! 

 SELECT 
  c.ID, Color, WebColor, ProductID, ColorID,
  CASE WHEN b.ProductID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS SELECTED
 FROM Product_Colors c 
 lEFT OUTER JOIN Product_Colors_Bridge b ON b.ColorID = c.ID  
 WHERE b.ProductID = @PRODUCTID OR b.ProductID IS NULL